# How to check that solr server is running

Tags: ajax, json, solr

i have implemented search in my E commerce   application. which hit solr(running on port 8983) to get the search result

solr url is

```
url =solrURL+"/solr/db/select/?qt=dismax&wt=json&&start="+start+"&rows="+end+"&q="+lowerCaseQuery+"&hl=true&hl.fl=text&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&sort= score desc ,"+sort+" "+order+"&json.wrf=?"
```

and using getJson i am getting the solr response.

```
 $.getJSON(url, function(result){
```

now my problem is how can i determine that solr server is running.

**EDIT:**

$

```
.ajax({
                url: "http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/admin/ping",
                    success:function(){
                            alert("ok");
                        },
                        error: function()
                        {
                            alert("dsd");                       
                        }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a timeout value. Though `getJSON` does not specify one you may use the jquery method `$.ajax` see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback,
  timeout: 3000 //3 second timeout
});
```

For the ping you may check the following snippet:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/admin/ping',
  type: 'GET',
  complete: function(transport) {
     if(transport.status == 200) {
         alert('Success');
     } else {
         alert('Failed');
     }
  }
 });
```

Comment: fyr: look at my edit. But the problem is it goes to in error function each time even if my server is running. when i debug through firebugg than i got 200 as status code than also it goes into error block. what could be the problem??

Comment: if u think that my url is incorrect, i tested it with http://www.google.co.in/ too. but still getting the same result

Comment: I added an additional snippet.

Comment: fyr: though solr server is running , i am getting status as 0..what can b the problem??

Comment: One possible problem can be that 192.168.1.9 is not reachable from your site or you block ports somehow

Comment: even if i am using google.co.in in url than also i am getting 0