# how to set a request timeout error handler using Ajax-solr

Tags: javascript, jquery, solr

I'm trying to do [what this guy is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800073/how-to-check-that-solr-server-is-running) - basically check that my Solr server is running, **except** I'm not using jQuery with getJSON, I'm using the [ajax-solr](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr) library. There's got to be a proper way to set a timeout handler within the library itself. After scouring the [documentation](http://evolvingweb.github.com/ajax-solr/docs/) I haven't been able to figure it out.

Is there a proper way to set this timeout? Right now I've got a very inelegant solution that's just checking if a div has been filled after a setTimeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax-solr sends all its requests through this method: https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/blob/master/managers/Manager.jquery.js

You can create your own custom Manager that sets a timeout and handles it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the global setting for ajax, for that you have to include the jquery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
timeout:3000,
complete:function(jxhr,status){
if(status=='timeout'){alert('timedout');}
}
});

//rest of ajax-solr code here
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but unfortunately this app uses a multitude of different ajax requests, so I can't use a global generic handler for all of them.